# Imagemagick: set IPTC parameters in jpeg image

Tags: images, imagemagick, jpeg

With the Imagemagick command

```
$ identify -verbose image.jpg
```

so many properties of the image are shown. 
For example, in the output I can find

```
Profiles:
Profile-8bim: 1058 bytes
Profile-iptc: 1017 bytes
  Image Name[2,5]: 01-00241624000002h
  Credit[2,110]: owner
  Caption[2,120]: some description
```

But how to set those parameters? In particular, I would like to set the `Caption[2,120]` parameters to substitute the text `some description` with other words. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Perl package [`Image::ExifTool`](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-9.53/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod). It includes a command-line program called `exiftool` that can change EXIF, IPTC, XMP, and many other forms of [image metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_metadata#Photographs):

```
$ exiftool -IPTC:caption="This is a great image" image.jpg
```

ExifTool understands [a great many other tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/) as well.

There's a good chance that your OS has an ExifTool package already. It's in the Ubuntu package repository as `libimage-exiftool-perl`, in FreeBSD Ports as `graphics/p5-Image-ExifTool`, and in OS X Homebrew as `exiftool`, for example. The [official site](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) distributes Mac OS X and Windows standalone versions.

If you have [`cpanm`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) on your system, the second easiest way to install `exiftool` is:

```
$ sudo cpanm Image::ExifTool
```

You can also install through [`cpan`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN/scripts/cpan), which is only slightly more involved, once you get past all the questions it asks the first time you run it:

```
# cpan
cpan> install Image::ExifTool
cpan> exit
```

If you have neither `cpanm` nor `cpan` installed, even installing from source is not hard:

```
# cd /tmp
# wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/E/EX/EXIFTOOL/Image-ExifTool-9.53.tar.gz
# tar xvf Image-ExifTool-9.53.tar.gz
# cd Image-ExifTool-9.53
# perl Makefile.PL
# make install
```

Run the program without arguments to get a detailed manual page.